# Get MFA status per user in B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

Is there a way to check (for example via the Microsoft Graph) if a user that is created via B2C custom policies has enabled/disabled multi-factor authentication (MFA) in Azure B2C? We want to get this status so we can nudge users that's didn't enable MFA yet.

We looked at following options but these are not supported for Azure B2C:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-get?view=graph-rest-beta
  (This method is available only for standard Azure AD and B2B users, but not B2C users.)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-list-credentialuserregistrationdetails (here we get the Authentication_RequestFromNonPremiumTenantOrB2CTenant error)

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and below is the result**

> Note: Currently **MS graph API** cannot access the **MFA phone numbers** of the users that are stored either using the default **user flows** or using the **custom policies** in **Azure Ad B2C**

I have created a B2C user and added an authentication method.

[image]

Now, I enabled **MFA** for the same user.

[image]

To obtain a user's authentication methods or **MFA phone number** in **Azure AD B2C**, use below **MS graph API** query.

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ObjectID/authentication/methods
```

You can check **Azure AD B2C** user **Object ID** by following the steps.

**Azure AD B2C > Users > select the user**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: That works indeed for users that are created via the Azure Portal portal itself but not if a user was created via an Azure B2C custom policy...

Comment: Currently MS graph API cannot access the MFA phone numbers of the users that are stored either using the default user flows or using the custom policies in Azure Ad B2C.